# Multiple RewriteBase in apache

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

I rarely dabble in the server side setup.  Here is what I am attempting to do in my .htaccess file. http://domain.com/variable should rewrite to http://domain.com/home.php?aid=variable

To do this I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/www>
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?aid=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

I want to be able to do this as well now:
http://domain.com/webinar/variable should rewrite to http://domain.com/webinar.php?aid=variable

Do i need a second rewrite base with the same rule or just another rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a new RewriteRule. A new RewriteBase directive would be excessive because you'd need to write another RewriteRule anyway.

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/www>
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # Stop execution if request is for an existing file or directory
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [L]

 # Rewrite webinar/variable to webinar.php?aid=variable
 RewriteRule ^webinar/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ webinar.php?aid=$1 [L]

 # Rewrite variable to index.php?aid=variable
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ index.php?aid=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi Kjetilh, thanks for the reply!  I added the `RewriteRule . - [L]`  and I added `RewriteRule ^webinar/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ /webinar.php?aid=$1 [L]` above the index rewrite like you have there.  When I go to http://domain.com/webinar/variable it gives me a Not Found - The requested URL /webinar/variable was not found on this server. I don't have to restart apache or anything do I?

Comment: @tomjung As you seem to have added these rules in the server  configuration contrary to a .htaccess file, yes I think you must restart Apache

Comment: Thanks! I'm setup on a virtual host something or other.  I restarted and it worked!